# How do I match textarea tags with a certain attribute?

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to match textarea tags with a certain attribute only. Given I have this string:

```
{{one}}

<div>{{two}}</div>

<textarea data-match-this="true">{{three}}</textarea>

<textarea>{{four}}</textarea>

{{five}}
```

I currently have this regex:

```
({{(?!#|\/).*?}})(?!<textarea>)(?!<\/textarea\>)
```

That currently matches all tags except for the ones inside the textarea's. What regex can I use to enable it to match the tags inside the textarea with the "data-match-this='true'" attribute?

Here is my Rubular: https://rubular.com/r/RuVrypBsdDVJii

Comment: Can there be textareas with a different class?

Comment: Yes, there can be textareas with a different class. Maybe we can have an attribute like the following, instead using class: data-match-this="true". I will revise my question.

Comment: By default, it shouldn't match any tags inside textarea, except for textareas that have the "data-match-this='true'" tag. It should match all other tags on the page. Hope that makes sense and let me know if I can clarify

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow your requirements then. Can you post a list of the matches you want to get?

Comment: Yes, on the Rubular (https://rubular.com/r/RuVrypBsdDVJii), I've matched {{one}}, {{two}}, and {{five}}. I want to modify the regex to also match {{three}}. That is, I want to match all tags except for {{four}}.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. Is `(?<!data\-match\-this="true">)({{.*?}})` sufficient, or might it be possible that there are more attributes in the element?

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser like [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri)?

Comment: Thanks, ggorlen! This is almost there, but it's just matching {{four}} instead of {{three}}. Is it possible to do the opposite, and match {{three}} instead of the {{four}} tag? Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Oh, whoops--try `(?<!textarea>)({{.*?}})`?

Comment: `Nokogiri::HTML(html_variable).css('textarea[data-match-this]')`

Comment: I think it's easier if I just use your first solution because the second textarea may have other attributes. I changed the code to use a data-do-not-match-this="true" tag instead: https://rubular.com/r/HxJQhlxWD6WbFi. It works great! If you post your answer, I'll check it as the accepted solution :) Thanks ggorlen!!

Comment: Thanks for your help 3limin4t0r. I'm trying to match all the other tags too on the page :) I think ggorlen got it

Comment: Hi ggorlen, if there are more attributes in the element, is there a regex to ignore the extra attributes? See for example: https://rubular.com/r/dTZVlEpci2EJck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this expression might work, with maybe a bit modification:

```
^((?=(.*?<textarea.*(data-match-this="true".*))>)|(?!(.*?<textarea.*>))).*?({{(?!#|\/).*?}}).*$
```

which is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/0M0Zwx/1/), if you wish to explore further or simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/0M0Zwx/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, Emma! There would be other attributes in the second textarea tag. If so, is there a way to only match with the textarea that has the "data-match-this" attribute?

Comment: AMAZING! I modified your solution a little bit to just match the tags: https://rubular.com/r/pXmbTXfUqsEKN5. It works great! Thank you so much Emma!!! :)

Comment: Hi again Emma. If the tags are all on the same line, how can I match them? I tried adding a ? instead of a $ at the end, but can only match the first tag. See here: https://rubular.com/r/g6otktRF7NObGt

Comment: Oh sorry again! I see this might be more complicated than I expected. I saw that the regex won't take new lines into account: https://rubular.com/r/okL75rmrur5O2W

Comment: No prob! Thanks again Emma :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it like this

`/<textarea(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sdata-match-this\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*true\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>([\S\s]*?)<\/textarea\s*>/`

https://regex101.com/r/Oy6vQd/1

Where the content is in group 2.
Note - the position of the attribute/value searched for
is independent, it can be anywhere in the tag.

Explained

```
 # Begin open textarea tag

 < textarea 
 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s data-match-this \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           \s* true \s*           # data-match-this = true
           \1 
      )
 )
                        # Have the data-match-this = true, 
                        # just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]? )+

 >                      # End span tag

 ( [\S\s]*? )           # (2), textarea content
 </textarea \s* >       # Close textarea tag
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution sln. I'm also trying to match {{one}}, {{two}}, and {{five}} too, in addition to {{three}}. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to match only textarea tags (including ones with classes and ones with no content) with `data-match-this='true'` using this 
 regex: `<textarea.*data-match-this="true".*>.*<\/textarea>`. If you need to capture the content, just add some parentheses like so: `<textarea.*data-match-this="true".*>(.*)<\/textarea>`. To make it only get tags with content, change the last `.*` to `.+`: `<textarea.*data-match-this="true".*>.+<\/textarea>`

Comment: Thanks ldtcoop. Appreciate your help! I'm also trying to match the other tags on the page outside of the textarea tags too

Comment: Ahh! I understand now. I have an idea of how to do that, but I just stepped away from my computer. If no one has figured this out by the time I get back to one, I'll see if my idea pans out